# Append more data to an api defined in a common class

Tags: ios, swift

I'm calling a webservice like so...

`WebServiceClient.shared.getNearbyLocationsList(with.....`

This in turn calls another class like so..

```
func getNearbyLocationsList(withParameters parameters: APIParameters, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, [String: Any]?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = APIClient.shared.createWebServiceUrl(forPath: WebServicePath.googleLocationsApi, withParameters: .....
```

And here, this part `WebServicePath.googleLocationsApi..` calls this variable in another class...

```
static let googleLocationsApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json"
let googleKey = "YOUR GOOGLE KEY"
```

So this will be the api url called. But my actual location url looks something like this...

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?sensor=true&location=10.123456,78.910111&radius=1000&key=googleKey
```

So this entire portion has to be appended with the url given above at `static let googleLocationsApi =....`:

```
?sensor=true&location=10.123456,78.910111&radius=1000&key=Aqporjp9asdjhg425jhgjhgvbjhAJGFKJfkjgkj4kjakjfb
```

Here, location, radius and key is defined somewhere else. So how can I have an api structure that will take these values and thus have the final api..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `URLComponent` to encode the queryparameters in URL.
Example:-

```swift
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: googleLocationsApi)!
urlComponents.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "sensor", value: true),
    URLQueryItem(name: "location", value: "10.123456,78.910111")
]
urlComponents.url      // this should give you the url you expect.
```

For more details go here:- https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/constructing-urls-in-swift
This is a great post by John Sundell explaining it in details

Answer (score 0):

@Aks, your answer is right, I've made couple of changes by adding a function by which you can pass your dynamic params with it.

```
 let googleKey = "YOUR GOOGLE KEY"
 var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: googleLocationsApi)!
 urlComponents.queryItems = appendQueryItems(queryItems: ["sensor": true,"radius":1000, "location": "10.123456,78.910111", "key": googleKey])

 debugPrint(urlComponents.url!)
```

**Function definition**

```
func appendQueryItems(queryItems: [String: Any]) -> [URLQueryItem] {

    var urlQueryItems = [URLQueryItem]()
    for (key,value) in queryItems {
        urlQueryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: "\(key)", value: "\(value)"))
    }

    return urlQueryItems
}
```